# deleting empty values from list inside list

Tags: python, regex, list

i need help on how to delete null, empty string from a list inside list.

```
res = [ ['', 'ACTION', 'ADVENTURE', 'FANTASY', ''],
 ['', 'ACTION', 'DRAMA', 'ROMANCE', ''],
 ['', 'HISTORY', 'ROMANCE', 'WAR', ''],
 ['', 'DRAMA', 'THRILLER', ''],
 ['', 'DRAMA', 'THRILLER', ''],
 ['', 'COMEDY', 'DRAMA', 'ROMANCE', ''],
 ['', 'ADVENTURE', 'COMEDY', ''],
 ['', 'ACTION', 'THRILLER', '']]
```

if it was like

```
res = ['', 'ACTION', 'ADVENTURE', 'FANTASY', '']
```

i would do

```
res = [x for x in res if x ]
```

But how to remove from list inside list.
Please suggest.

And  i also need to find each  item count from that list  eg. count of ACTION,count of THRILLER .

Comment: Remove first and last element from each sublist

Comment: @Tushar That relies on the assumption that they'll always be in this structure, which may not be the case.

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
res1 = [[i for i in j if i] for j in res]
dictt = {}
[[dictt.__setitem__(i, dictt.setdefault(i, 0) + 1) for i in j] for j in res1]
```

Comment: @martineau by this i am getting count of items in res list(main list or parent list) i:e 8. But i want to find the count of Action then count of comedy like wise.

Comment: nope, instead i am getting none none values in place of every items.

Comment: You'll get count in dictt. It works fine at my side.

Comment: @ user2393267 Thanks  got it.but while executing that why some lines shows up showing those none valued lists.CAn u please explain?

Answer (score 3):

Map and filter the res list:

```
map(lambda x:filter(lambda y: y != "", x), res)


>>> map(lambda x:filter(lambda y: y != "", x), res)
[['ACTION', 'ADVENTURE', 'FANTASY'], ['ACTION', 'DRAMA', 'ROMANCE'], ['HISTORY', 'ROMANCE', 'WAR'], ['DRAMA', 'THRILLER'], ['DRAMA', 'THRILLER'], ['COMEDY', 'DRAMA', 'ROMANCE'], ['ADVENTURE', 'COMEDY'], ['ACTION', 'THRILLER']]
```

For counting:

```
import collections
c = Counter(reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, filtered_res))

>>> filtered_res= map(lambda x:filter(lambda y: y != "", x), res)
>>> c = Counter(reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, filtered_res))
>>> c["DRAMA"]
4
```

Comment: so please tell how to get count of each items.

Comment: I really like to use reduce . I could use Counter also now , great to know.

Comment: @AkshayHazari, map, reduce and all built-in functions are really fast compared to loops for example, is always a good practice to use them. Also functional programming is really fun :D

Comment: Yeah . Had done a bit of Haskell coding before starting python and finding map, reduce (foldr) , filter , its just impossible to not use them.

Comment: Yeah, haskeller here too, once you pop there is no stop

Answer (score 1):

Using 'old-fashioned` for loops, you can remove the empty entries and get the total count by category:

```
res = [ ['', 'ACTION', 'ADVENTURE', 'FANTASY', ''],
 ['', 'ACTION', 'DRAMA', 'ROMANCE', ''],
 ['', 'HISTORY', 'ROMANCE', 'WAR', ''],
 ['', 'DRAMA', 'THRILLER', ''],
 ['', 'DRAMA', 'THRILLER', ''],
 ['', 'COMEDY', 'DRAMA', 'ROMANCE', ''],
 ['', 'ADVENTURE', 'COMEDY', ''],
 ['', 'ACTION', 'THRILLER', '']]

counts = {}
cleaned = []
for categories in res:        
    cleaned.append([]);
    for category in categories:        
        if category !='':           
            cleaned[-1].append(category) 
            if category in counts:
                counts[category]= counts[category] +1
            else:
                counts[category]=1;            

print counts['ACTION']
```

Comment: Thanks but if by using your code can i  get my preferred  item's count like count(ACTION) = ?.